# Frequent Flyer (Downgrading)

Tags: loyalty-programs, oneworld

I am holding a platinum topbonus card (oneworld emerald) from airberlin but I am quite sure I cannot clock up 100k miles such that I sustain my status by June 2016 this year.

Currently, I have 52k / 100k and 50k miles is the gold status (oneworld sapphire).

**What will happen when my platinum status is due in June?**

**Would I bounce back to the gold status and I get to keep my gold status for 1 more year (till June 2017) since I have 52k/50k miles?** Or would I be reset to the normal (red) status and start from 0 miles again? If it's the latter, that will be pretty sad =(

**Also, if I apply for a visa card with airberlin topbonus before my platinum card expires, would my status be extended?** Or will I still either reset or downgrade to gold once June 2016 comes?

**Given my platinum status, would any other airline loyalty program want to match my status?** I really don't mind switching to Star Alliance.

Comment: Affiliated credit cards do not usually give you status, they only give you more points towards status.  Now maybe if you get it and quickly spend enough to earn another 48K, then OK but that is likely a lot of spending even with any bonuses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: **since you have qualified for Gold this year, you will drop back to Gold.**

And yes, many airlines will "status match" top-tier flyers in other airline programs, just figure out which ones would be good for your flying patterns and Google.  This may or may not require meeting a "challenge" to fly a certain amount with the new airline though, and you generally only get one shot (per airline) to do this.

Comment: http://www.statusmatcher.com/airlines ;P